# Form field border width for colorblind people

Tags: accessibility

We have an issues when it comes to accessibility for web forms. During validation what should be the form field border width, 1px or 2px ?

Hope this will be little clear:
Should I have a 2px red border or 1px red border for the error field so that it will be easy for the colorblind people.
[image: Should I have a 2px red border or 1px red border for the error field so that it will be easy for the colorblind people.]

Comment: I fail to see the UX question in here.  Would you please expand on it?

Comment: We need a little more information here. What's your problem with this border ?

Comment: Hi JonW, JohnGB, Dacquin I have added extra information. Let me know whether its helpful to clear my question.

Comment: If someone is colourblind and can't distinguish red from another colour then it's not really going to matter if it's 1px or 50px.  Make sure [Color is not used as the only visual means of conveying information, indicating an action, prompting a response, or distinguishing a visual element](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-without-color.html)

Comment: Hi JonW, thanks for clarifying. 

Irrespective of the color, If i use 2px instead of 1px border width, will it be beneficial for the colorblind to differentiate between a normal form field and the form field with an error (I already have a Alert icon in the field).

Comment: @ThulasiRam welcome.  Please provide more details.  "We have an issue with accessibility" tells us nothing about what the issue is....are users confused? abandoning the form? failing to follow instructions?  What do other fields in the form look like?  It's almost impossible to design just one field without understanding what you are trying to achieve with the form and what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no definite answer as to whether the border should be 1px or 2px. You will need to make a judgement as to how thick the border needs to be in order for it to change the shape of the field sufficiently to differentiate it from other fields (I doubt 1px would be noticeable though.)

However, how are you identifying the invalid fields for people who cannot see the visual clue afforded by the border? Someone using a screenreader will be completely unaware of the border. You must have an explanation in text in addition to the visual clues.

Comment: As Matt said, it's not a matter of thickness but colors only. You can test all your mockups with this tool : http://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/ to see the render.